# Array buffer and winapi

Tags: c, windows, winapi, pixmap

### Context :

- Windows 10
- WinAPI and C code

### Question :

I have a buffer of pixel represented as `uint8_t buffer[width * height * PIXEL_SIZE]` that i would like to regularly modify the content data and redraw the buffer into the window.

I'm encoutering two issues with the winapi with which one i'm lost :

- How do i print a buffer of pixel onto the window ?
- How do i redraw later in the code the dame modifies buffer ?

I have made many researchs but no code snippet have successfully helped me to solve my issue.

Here is a **not working code sample** in order to show what i would like to archieve with the elements of code i have:

#### new_image.c

```
// Global variables
static HDC      hdc;
static HDC      context_hdc;
static HBITMAP  hDib;
static HGDIOBJ  obj;

static void     set_bmi_object(BITMAPINFO *bmi, int width, int height) {
    memset(bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

    bmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
}

// Allocate a new image buffer
void             *new_image(HWND hwnd, int width, int height)
{
    BITMAPINFO  bmi;
    BYTE        *bits = NULL;
    void        *buffer;

    if (NULL == (buffer = (char*)malloc(width * height * PIXEL_SIZE)))
        return (NULL);

    set_bmi_object(&bmi, width, height);

    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    hDib = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bits), 
                            NULL, 0);

    if (hDib != NULL) {
        context_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        if (context_hdc == NULL) {
            DeleteObject(hDib);
        } else {
            obj = SelectObject(context_hdc, hDib);
            CopyMemory(bits, buffer, width * height * sizeof(PIXEL_SIZE));
        }
    }

    return (newimg);
}

// Print the buffer of pixel on the window
void             put_image_to_window(HWND hwnd, void *buffer, int x, int y)
{
    (void)hwnd;

    // Void buffer because i should use directly HDCcontext_hdc linked to HGDIOBJ   obj ?
    (void)buffer;

    BitBlt(hdc, // destination
        x,
        y,
        500, // width of the region
        500, // height
        context_hdc, // source
        0,   // x
        0,   // y
        SRCCOPY);

    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
```

#### main.c

```
static const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

static void paint(HWND hwnd) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        paint(hwnd);
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void) {
    MSG             Msg;
    HINSTANCE       hInstance;
    HWND            hwnd;
    STARTUPINFOA    startup_info;
    WNDCLASSEX      wc;
    HWND            hwnd;

    GetStartupInfoA(&startup_info);

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));

    // Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    // ... etc
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT(g_szClassName);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        return (-1);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Title,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 
        500,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return (-1);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, startup_info.wShowWindow);


    image = new_image(hwnd, 500, 500);

    put_image_to_window(hwnd, image, 0, 0);

    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return (Msg.wParam);
}
```

Here is in `new_image.c`

- a function `new_image` that returns a pointer on a buffer of pixels,
- a function `put_image_to_window` that display the buffer of pixels on the window.

Comment: If UpdateWindow isn't working, you can probably trigger a redraw with [InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect), and if your WM_PAINT handler can use it you can then be specific about the bit that's changed.

Comment: @Rup i think for the specific bytes that changed, you are talking about PAINTSTRUCT, i will document about it. But actually, the WM_PAINT event case do not use the buffer, i've seen some people use BitBlt in the WM_PAINT case, and other outside WndProc

Comment: You are drawing outside the `WM_PAINT` handler, so anything you draw will be overwritten at the next paint request. And your `WM_PAINT` handler draws nothing, so it will just draw your `wc.hbrBackground`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for your reponse ! So if every draw pass through WM_PAINT, does it mean that i cannot draw outside WM_PAINT handler like i am trying to do ?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Painting and Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/painting-and-drawing). Make sure to read *all* of it.

Comment: You have to be able to do all your drawing inside WM_PAINT anyway, because you need to regenerate your content if the user minimizes the window and then restores it. If you draw outside of WM_PAINT, you need to remember enough information so that WM_PAINT can replicate what you did. Most people just let WM_PAINT do all the drawing. Avoids code duplication.

Comment: There are two ways to handle this situation: 1) the "old" way by handling `WM_PAINT`, where the pixels are put into an `HBITMAP` that is then re-drawn onto the window's `HDC` every time `WM_PAINT` is received; 2) the "new" way using the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style with the `UpdateLayeredWindow()` function. Put the pixels into an `HBITMAP` and create an in-memory `HDC` to select it into, then pass that `HDC` to `UpdateLayeredWindow()` and do not handle `WM_PAINT` at all. Whenever the pixels are changed, simply call `UpdateLayeredWindow()` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Thanks to the answers from @RemyLebeau @IInspectable @Raymond Chen and @BarmakShemirani answers, here is a solution.

Now i successfully update the window according to buffer obtained with the `CreateDIBSection()` function, without passing through the `WM_PAINT` event.

I use the `UpdateLayeredWindow()` function to update the window's pixels.

Here is the solution code :

#### new_image.c

```
// global variables
static HBITMAP hDib;

static void     set_bmi_object(BITMAPINFO *bmi, int width, int height) {
    memset(bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

    bmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
}

// Allocate a new image buffer
void             *new_image(HWND hwnd, int width, int height)
{
    BITMAPINFO  bmi;
    void        *buffer;
    HDC         hdc;

    set_bmi_object(&bmi, width, height);

    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    hDib = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&buffer), NULL, 0);

    ReleaseDC(instance->win_list->hwnd, hdc);

    return (buffer);
}

// Print the buffer of pixel on the window
void             put_image_to_window(HWND hwnd, void *buffer, int x, int y)
{
    HDC                     hdc;
    HDC                     context_hdc;
    HGDIOBJ                 old_obj;

    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    context_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    old_obj = SelectObject(context_hdc, hDib);

    BitBlt(hdc,
        0,
        0,
       500,
       500,
       context_hdc,
       0,
       0,
       SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(context_hdc, old_obj);

    DeleteDC(context_hdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

    // Call UpdateLayeredWindow
    BLENDFUNCTION blend = {0};
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 128;// half transparent
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
    POINT ptLocation = {x, y};
    SIZE szWnd = {500, 500};
    POINT ptSrc = {0, 0};
    UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd, hdc, &ptLocation, &szWnd, context_hdc, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);
}
```

#### main.c

```
static const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void) {
    MSG             Msg;
    HINSTANCE       hInstance;
    HWND            hwnd;
    STARTUPINFOA    startup_info;
    WNDCLASSEX      wc;
    HWND            hwnd;

    GetStartupInfoA(&startup_info);

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));

    // Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    // ... etc
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT(g_szClassName);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        return (-1);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Title,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 
        500,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return (-1);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, startup_info.wShowWindow);

    image = new_image(hwnd, 500, 500);

    put_image_to_window(hwnd, image, 0, 0);

    // The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return (Msg.wParam);
}
```

Here is a must read that @IInspectable gave, for WinAPI beginners like me : [Painting and Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/painting-and-drawing).

Should have read this before questionning ...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CopyMemory(bits, buffer, width * height * sizeof(PIXEL_SIZE));
> ```

Usage of `sizeof` operator is not correct. A bitmap can be 1, 4, 8, 16, 24, or 32 bit. A 32-bit bitmap has 4 bytes per pixel. If `PIXEL_SIZE` is declared as `int32_t` then by coincidence you get the right size. Otherwise use the correct formula to calculate size.

Also, there is no point in copying `buffer` to `bits`. You can use `bits` directly. `bits` will be valid as long as you have not destroyed `hDib`

> ```
> hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
> ```

A call to `GetDC` should end with `ReleaseDC`, otherwise you may end up with resource leak. Windows device context is not meant to be stored as a constant. Use it as temporary value instead.

You also have declared `HDC context_hdc` as global variable. This is okay for memory device context, but it's not necessary. The only global variable you need is `hDib` and perhaps `buffer`

```
#include <windows.h>

static const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
static HBITMAP  hDib;

BYTE *new_image(int width, int height)
{
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    BYTE *buffer;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    hDib = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&buffer), NULL, 0);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    return buffer;
}

static void paint(HWND hwnd) 
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    if(hDib)
    {
        HDC context_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(context_hdc, hDib);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 500, 500, context_hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(context_hdc, old_obj);
        DeleteDC(context_hdc);
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        paint(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if(hDib)
        {
            //draw something
            HDC context_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
            HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(context_hdc, hDib);

            SetDCBrushColor(context_hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            int x = (int)(short)LOWORD(lParam);
            int y = (int)(short)HIWORD(lParam);
            RECT rc = { x, y, x + 10, y + 10};
            FillRect(context_hdc, &rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

            SelectObject(context_hdc, old_obj);
            DeleteDC(context_hdc);

            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void) {
    MSG             Msg;
    HINSTANCE       hInstance;
    HWND            hwnd;
    STARTUPINFOA    startup_info;
    WNDCLASSEX      wc;

    GetStartupInfoA(&startup_info);
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT(g_szClassName);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName, "Title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    BYTE* image = new_image(500, 500);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);//startup_info.wShowWindow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    if (hDib)
        DeleteObject(hDib);

    return (Msg.wParam);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried from your example to write into `BYTE* image = new_image(500, 500);` just after the call this way :  `for (size_t i = 0; i < 500 * 500; i++) { ((uint32_t*)image)[i] = 0xF0; }` but actually it is failling. The `BYTE* image` seems to not be allocated the size 500 * 500  by `CreateDIBSection`